# ViewPager OnAdapterChangeListener to set the first page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am trying to build a circular `ViewPager` where I don't have to make any settings from the outside. 
In order for this ViewPager to have circular scrolling, I need to put a copy of the last image at the start (index 0) and a copy of the first image at the end. This mean that my `ViewPager` has to start at index 1, not index 0.
I can easily do this from the outside by calling `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`, but I want to encapsulate this in the `PagerAdapter` itself.

My problem is finding an appropriate callback method to do that. It doesn't work in the constructor of the `PagerAdapter`.

One way that seems to work is by adding an `OnAdapterChangeListener` like in my code below. Is that legit or will I run into trouble?

```
public class CircularViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> imageUrls;
private int lastIndex;
private int position = 1;

CircularViewPagerAdapter(Context context, final ViewPager viewPager, List<String> imageUrls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    if (imageUrls.size() > 1) {
        imageUrls.add(0, imageUrls.get(imageUrls.size() - 1));
        imageUrls.add(imageUrls.get(1));
        lastIndex = imageUrls.size() - 1;
    }

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            CircularViewPagerAdapter.this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (position == 0) viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastIndex - 1, false);
            if (position == lastIndex) viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdapterChanged(@NonNull ViewPager viewPager, @Nullable PagerAdapter oldAdapter, @Nullable PagerAdapter newAdapter) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageUrls.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrls.get(position))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    container.addView(imageView);

    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving the Circle View Pager i have found the solution here. you just have to customize the View pager by using the below classes from [SOURCE HERE](https://github.com/waylife/InfiniteViewPager/tree/master/infiniteviewpager/src/main/java/com/zanlabs/widget/infiniteviewpager)

```
InfinitePagerAdapter.java,  
InfiniteViewPager.java,  
RecycleBin.java,   
RecyclingPagerAdapter.java
```

After that use **`InfinitePagerAdapter`** instant of **`PagerAdapter`**.